# Entity Framework error: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model class called `Transaction` (Entity Framework code-first if that matters). Part of the class is:

```
private List<Client> _clients;

public List<Client> Clients
{
    get
    {
        if (_clients != null)
        {
            return _clients;
        }
    
        return new List<Client>() 
        {
                new Client()
                {
                    FirstName = "[Client Name]",
                    LastName = "[No client added.]",
                }
        };
    }
    set
    {
        _clients = value;
    }
}
```

I have added the `Transaction` model to IdentityModels. If I run the code using this `Transaction` class, I get an error when I'm trying to instantiate `Transaction` at runtime:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

To confirm, the error takes place when I try to create a new `Transaction` object. So to get rid of record and create a new object, I just replaced above with:

```
public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

which obviously doesn't do the error/null checking as I want it to.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and equally important how to "fix" it? (i.e. implement the error checking without getting the runtime error). TIA

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the error happens. Surely it has something to do with Entity Framework trying to create and return the new list of clients when the existing list is null. At any rate, the now obvious solution to me that I ended up doing is just creating an accessor method that returns the value of Clients, rather than pushing the logic of the code inside of the get{}. Simply this:

```
public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }

public List<Client> GetClients
{
   //The null checking logic and return of Clients go here
}
```